# Wont show Sprite image?

Tags: html, css, menu

Why wont this show my sprite image as the background of the yellow bordered box?
There is an example here:

If anyone could come with some examples on what i should change, that would be great.

Here is my code:

Html:

```
<div class="repeat">
    <div style='width:100%;'>
        <div style='float:left;margin-top:107px;margin-left:50px;width:80px;height:100px;border:1px solid yellow;'>
            <div class="menu">
                <ul id='nav'>
                    <li class='front'><a href='?p=front'>Front</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div style='float:left;margin-top:107px;margin-left:10px;width:80px;height:100px;border:1px solid yellow;'></div>
        <div style='clear:both;'></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Css:

```
.repeat {
    float:left;
    width: 884px;
    height: auto;
    min-height:700px;
    background: url(images/repeat.png) repeat-y;
    z-index:2;
}

.menu {
    width:80px;
    height:100px;
    position:relative;
    }
    ul#nav {
        list-style: none inside;
        }
        ul#nav li {
            display: inline;
            }
            ul#nav li a {
                display: block;
                height: 40px;
                float: left;
                }
                ul#nav li.front  a{
                    width:80px;
                    background: url(images/menu/p1.png) top center no-repeat;
                    }               
                    ul#nav li a:hover {
                        background-position: bottom center;
                    }
                ul#nav li.front2  a{
                    width:80px;
                    background: url(images/menu/p1.png) bottom center no-repeat;
                }
```

Comment: try putting the absolute rather than the relative url in `background: url('images/menu/p1.png')...`

Comment: Huh? The yellow-bordered boxes have no `background-image` set.

Comment: As you can see the Ul nav is inside the div with yellow borders.. Why wouldnt they be showing their background then ?

Comment: the absolute url starts with "http://".  *Your* url calculates the file location *relative* to the file calling it.

Comment: Is your image where you think it is? If you type your URL into the address bar of your browser, does the image actually exist there?

Comment: Just sticking "http://" on the front of your path won't help. You have to be sure that the path is correct. ie `http://mywebsite.com/complete/path/to/images/menu/p1.png`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `background-image` shows up fine, except that part of the spritemap (`center top`) is empty, and it's set to `no-repeat`. Also, you have not reset your list, which makes the child elements oddly offset.

Revise:

```
ul#nav { padding: 0; }

ul#nav li.front a {
      background: url("images/menu/p1.png") repeat-y center bottom transparent;
      width: 80px;
      height: 87px;
}
```

This will probably not solve all your problems. It is not evident from your markup and CSS what you are trying to achieve. You might have better luch with some absolute positioning of your anchor tag ... or simply do some cleanup.

Comment: Look at my code now Nix. I found out how to show the Background. But why is it to far to the right?

Comment: Because a `ul` by default has a padding of `1em`, which you have not accounted for. This is why the first line in my example resets it to 0.

Comment: There are other issues also. There are multiple elements with the same `ID` (`ul#nav`). An `ID` has to be unique.

Answer (score 2):

Your Sprite is showing just fine... 
Just that it's not visible in the overall setting.
Try adding height: 80px to your "ul#nav li.front a" selector and you will see where you are going wrong. 
Try on yourself from there.

Hint: Use your browser developer tools (I prefer Chrome) and hover over each element to see what area they occupy. In your case check the 'div menu' and 'li a' elements.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it - there was no rule that targeted the boxes you want styled.
And if you don't want a single red image that spans the gap between the two, you need to remove the rule for the "ul#nav li.front a" selector.

```
.yellowBox
{
    float: left;
    margin-top: 107px;
    width: 80px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid yellow;
    background-image: url(images/menu/p1.png);
}

#box1
{
    margin-left: 50px;
}

#box2
{
    margin-left: 10px;
}


<div class="repeat">
    <div style="width:100%;">
        <div class='yellowBox' id='box1'>
            <div class="menu">
                <ul id="nav">
                    <li class="front"><a href="?p=front">Front</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class='yellowBox' id='box2'></div>
        <div style="clear:both;"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```